# Parsing and cleaning text file in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a text file which contains raw data. I want to parse that data and clean it so that it can be used further.The following is the rawdata.

```
"{\x0A    \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A        \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A        \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A        \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22id\x22: {\x0A        \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A        \x22uuid\x22: \x221a0d4d6e-0c00-11e7-a16f-0242ac110002\x22,\x0A        \x22device_id\x22: \x22423e49efa4b8b013\x22\x0A    },\x0A    \x22stats\x22: [\x0A        {\x0A            \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-03-22T03:21:11+0000\x22,\x0A            \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A            \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A            \x22values\x22: {\x0A                \x22device_id\x22: \x22423e49efa4b8b013\x22,\x0A                \x22language\x22: \x22en\x22\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}"
```

I want to remove all the hexadecimal characters,I tried parsing the data and storing in an array and cleaning it using re.sub() but it gives the same data.

```
for line in f:
    new_data = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f],\x22',r'', line)
    data.append(new_data)
```

Comment: is the file actually a string that has "\x0A" in it as 4 seperate characers? or are those actually just the representation of `'\x0a'` which is a single byte you would get in python? saying its the "rawdata" doesn't clarify what the data actually is

Comment: *I want to remove all hexadecimal characters*. Don't. The string looks like a json string, and the `\x22` characters are hexa code for double quote (`"`) and as such are *required*. What is the display of: `for line in f: print(line)`

Answer (score 0):

\x0A is the hex code for newline.  After `s = <your json string>`, `print(s)` gives

```
>>> print(s)
{
    "identifier": {
        "company_code": "TSC",
        "product_type": "airtime-ctg",
        "host_type": "android"
    },
    "id": {
        "type": "guest",
        "group": "guest",
        "uuid": "1a0d4d6e-0c00-11e7-a16f-0242ac110002",
        "device_id": "423e49efa4b8b013"
    },
    "stats": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2017-03-22T03:21:11+0000",
            "software_id": "A-ACTG",
            "action_id": "open_app",
            "values": {
                "device_id": "423e49efa4b8b013",
                "language": "en"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You should parse this with the `json` module `load` (from file) or `loads` (from string) functions.  You will get a dict with 2 dicts and a list with a dict.